# Change of variables: Jacobian

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the integral $$\iint x^2 + y^2e^{xy} dA $$
where D is the region in the positive quadrant bounded by the curves

$xy=1$

$xy=2$

$x^2-$$y^2$=$1$

$x^2-$$y^2$=$2$

Attempt:

$u$=$xy$

$v$=$x^2$ - $y^2$=$1$

Im having troubling with writing the equations x and y separately. I know x has to be in terms of u and v and y also has to be in terms of u and v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ to solve this. Note that $$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|= \dfrac 1{\left|\dfrac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|}$$

The result you get for $\left|\dfrac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|$ will be in terms of $x$ and $y$ instead of $u$ and $v$. But fortunately, for this particular integral, that will not be a problem.